# How to get ListView item id in a contextual menu

Tags: android, listview, multichoiceitems

I have a listView which does the following:

```
@Override
protected void onListItemClick(ListView l, View v, int position, long id) {
    super.onListItemClick(l, v, position, id);
    Intent i = new Intent(this, TodoDetailActivity.class);
    Uri todoUri = Uri.parse(MyTodoContentProvider.CONTENT_URI + "/" + id);
    i.putExtra(MyTodoContentProvider.CONTENT_ITEM_TYPE, todoUri);
    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),""+id,Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

    startActivity(i);
}
```

Note, there is a long id which I use to pass to the content provider to open a new activity and edit the "Todo" which is associated with the id.

Now I am trying to delete a "todo" through a contextual menu.

However, I don't know how to get the item id:

```
this.getListView().setMultiChoiceModeListener(new AbsListView.MultiChoiceModeListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemCheckedStateChanged(ActionMode actionMode, int i, long l, boolean b) {
            //Not Used
        }

        @Override
        public boolean onCreateActionMode(ActionMode actionMode, Menu menu) {
            MenuInflater inflater = actionMode.getMenuInflater();
            inflater.inflate(R.menu.context_menu, menu);
            return true;
        }

        @Override
        public boolean onPrepareActionMode(ActionMode actionMode, Menu menu) {
            return false;
        }

        @Override
        public boolean onActionItemClicked(ActionMode actionMode, MenuItem menuItem) {
            switch (menuItem.getItemId()) {
                case R.id.menu_delete_multiple:
                    for (int i = adapter.getCount() - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
                        if (getListView().isItemChecked(i)) {
                            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),""+i,Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                            AdapterView.AdapterContextMenuInfo info = (AdapterView.AdapterContextMenuInfo)menuItem.getMenuInfo();
                            Uri uri = Uri.parse(MyTodoContentProvider.CONTENT_URI+"/"+ what'sTHEIDE???);
                            getContentResolver().delete(uri, null, null);
                        }
                    }
                    fillData();
                    actionMode.finish(); // Action picked, so close the CAB
                    return true;
                default:
                    return false;
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onDestroyActionMode(ActionMode actionMode) {
            actionMode = null;
        }
    });
```

In my `onActionItemClicked()` area I would assume that I could get the same "long id" from the list view. What do I have to call to get the id to pass into the `onActionItemClicked()`?

As a beginner android programmer, I am a bit flabbergasted.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out I was overthinking this.

```
long mId = getListView().getAdapter().getItemId(i);
Uri uri = Uri.parse(MyTodoContentProvider.CONTENT_URI+"/"+ mId);
getContentResolver().delete(uri, null, null);
```

No complicated AdapterView methods are needed. info.id kept returning null since info was null so I just retrieved the id of the list view item that was clicked and passed it to the content provider to handle.